# /Zc:externC- compiler flag in vs 2022

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2022, compiler-options

Hi I am trying to convert an old project from vc++2013 to vc++ 2022.
I am getting a lot of C2733 Errors.
Most of them are related to overrides of memory allocation functions.
Here's one example

```
extern "C"
{
    void* _calloc_base( size_t nSize )
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

Based on my searching and reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-externc?view=msvc-170  I am supposed to add /Zc:externC- to compiler options.
But for some reason its not working for me.

[compiler flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpIlA.png)

I made a simple 1 file test project to replicate this. (Its not working even in my test proj)
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/g36wfk3xkt8jls0nbhqsv/externCTest.zip?rlkey=kaf0c3k2eln7ndlcytyhsswhy&dl=0

Comment: First, any code should be posted here, not in an external link that can go away at any time.  Second: `Hi I am trying to convert an old project from vc++2013 to vc++ 2022` and then you say `I am suppose to add /Zc:externC- to compiler options`.  If you're trying to convert a project to a newer version of the compiler, isn't one of the things you should be doing is *fixing* the compiler errors, and not covering them up?

Comment: Good points. Sorry, it's a first-time poster. I have updated the post with an example.

The project has warnings as errors turned on and I am trying to first get it to compile as it is first. It's a huge project so I thought that would be a good first step.
Once it's done I will remove ducktapes (compiler flags, disabled warnings, etc) 1 project at a time in the solution and fix it all one by one.

I am not sure what the right way to fix some of these bugs so its going to take time so getting it all to compile at first seems like a good idea for step 1.

Comment: So the old code tries to replace functions from the standard library. Icky! Turns out that VS 2013 and VS 2022 have different implementations of the library. So the "replace" functions don't match, and are considered overloads instead. And, of course, you cannot overload C functions. Cannot offer any solution to this, except a redesign.

Comment: Pay attention to the comboboxes at the top of the settings dialog.  You are not looking at the Configuration and Platform that you are actually building.  The warning is otherwise appropriate, `_calloc_base` has changed and acquired an extra parameter.  You need to make changes accordingly.  Buy Microsoft a cigar.

Comment: thanks for all the replies i am fixing all those core files by updating the function definations etc.
I was curious about the new changes and checked out new _calloc_Base func defination - 
`ALLOC_CALL void* _calloc_base(
 _In_ size_t _Count,
 _In_ size_t nSize )
{
 void* pMem = AllocUnattributed( nSize );
 memset( pMem, 0, nSize );
 return pMem;
}`

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title. Either post an answer below with your solution, if you want to share it, or delete the question altogether.